# Как вывести в административной панели данные связанной модели

Tags: django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я выбрал нужную мне книгу.Как мне отразить в поле audio только те файлы которые относятся к выбранной книге?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартными средствами вроде пока не решается. У меня [схожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1293400/django-inline-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0), для django 3.1 дописал доп метод и поля для автокомплит, чтобы при имзенении значения был запрос на получение доп данных, но из-за изменений в Django 3.2 все поломалось. тк они переместили автокомплит.

В результате думаю, что вы можете переопределить метод autocomlete моделей, чтобы они принимали доп аргументы (id связанного объекта) и фильтровать в AutocompleteView по этим полям. Это если с минимумом кода.

В противном случае придется писать доп точку API, доп поле c JS (для более гибкого и реюзабельного варианта), или писать JS для формы

---

UPD:

автокомплит в админке рано или поздно пригодится, когда будет много объектов и страница будет весить несколько мегабайт